# Executing code on App startup : Play API with scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playback

I have a requirement to create a microservice with scala and after exploring scalatra for couple of days, I switch back to Play framework. 
Need to download lucene index from blob on App startup and return an object of Index searcher to each controller, so that it's shared with in App. I am able to download index from blob using Guice DI i.e. creating a singleton class and doing eagerSingleton binding in Module. But unable to figure out how to return IndexSearcher object to each controller class.

Below is the code I have written so far:

```
class ApplicationStart @Inject()(clock: Clock, appLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle)  {
         Blob.fetch("influencers", "index")
}

class Module extends AbstractModule {

  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[ApplicationStart]).asEagerSingleton()

  }

@Singleton
class Controller @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def get(name: String) = Action { request =>
      val reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("index"), NoLockFactory.INSTANCE))
      val searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader)
      val resp = Searcher.searchIndex(name, searcher)
        Ok(resp.get.asInstanceOf[JsObject])
  }
}
```

Requirement is to create indexSearcher instance on App startup instead of creating in controller getName method and controller method should have access to that instance.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you post a sample code

Comment: [Your title isn't very descriptive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, what have you tried so far? Please post your code. We can't be much help without something to work with.

Comment: @James Thanks for your response, updated question statement. Please suggest.